# Swagger-UI Customizing using Angular 8 without any plugin

Tags: angular, angular-material, swagger-ui

on Swagger UI.. we see this when we click on schema. For my project I need similar thing to display on my UI. I am able to read the schema., but I am struggling to display schema on my screen.
do we have UI API for this ?I am using Angular 11 and back end Java.
[Click here for attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov1GX.png)

Comment: Its basic swagger configuration. Can you share your config file?

Comment: Basically I need to display the  schema like in attached image. Since the schema will have multiple nested objects, for each object I need to display the UI as in attached image.

Comment: That's quite clear from the OP. People would be able to help you better, if you share your config file. That helps us to understand if you need to tune some configurations or doing something wrong?